# Why might a chromecast-device incorrectly detect surround-sound in a TV-set?

Tags: audio, chromecast

Sometime within this last year (2021), my Chromecast devices (a 1st-generation and a 3rd generation) have
begun outputting garbled audio. (Voices are partially understandable, but there's choppy noise that makes
the videos almost unwatchable.)  This happens on all
three of the different TV models in my household.

[ Since it's a relatively recent issue, I'm wondering if
some Chromecast-firmware update might have contained changes in how the firmware detects the capabilities of
or existence of surround-sound in the TV. ]

And, what was really puzzling, is that if I do the casting
from my Win-10 laptop, I get this sound-garbling behavior.
But, if I do the cast from either my Android tablet (Nexus), or from a 5-year-old Chromebook, then the sound
is fine.

I finally stumbled upon a 'workaround' to prevent this from happening.  On both chromecast devices, I ran the 'Home' app device configuration and set the audio setting for surround-sound from "auto" detect to "stereo-only".

[ This happens from any/all of my various video files. Those video files are H.264 video-codec and AAC audio-codec, inside a std "MP4" container file, produced using the 'ffmpeg' program. ]

[ This issue relates specifically to Chromecast-devices.
When 'casting' to, say, a Roku-device, there are never
any audio issues. ]

[ The videos get deployed to a webpage where others can view them, and some of the viewers will no doubt be using a Chromecast device as their streaming-device of choice. ]

Does anyone have any insight as to why I might be having these audio garbling, when I cast from Windows-10?

TIA ... Dave

Comment: Not really a programming question, more suited for Video Production Stack Exchange?
Also, seeing your tags, does chromecast use FFmpeg? I didn't know that..

Comment: I claim this IS a programming question, in that it might be HTML or JS anomaly that is triggering the bad audio. (The ffmpeg should be removed...I don't see where I can accomplish that, so please do that for me. I mentioned that tag only because I use that tool in specifying the video/audio codecs.

Comment: Is Chromecast-device considered part of 'video production'?  Then, why does the tag appear here???

Comment: And, I looked in Video Production, and there is NOT a tag for Chromecast, so this certainly appears to be the correct forum for this question.

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly assumed you were a moderator.  And, I do now see how to remove (or insert) tags on my question. So, I have now removed it.

Comment: I'd recommend doing an `ffprobe` or `ffmpeg -i` on one of the problematic files and doing a Chromecast bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Damn...I erroneously thought I had solved this, but now the symptom is back!

The 'on-Windows-platform-only' aspect of my issue DID lead me to discover a group of Win-10 drivers that needed upgrading.  Applying those updates at first SEEMED to eliminate the audio garbling, but then a day later, the symptom came back.
(sigh)

My plan now, i guess, is to take a few deep breaths, and go learn something that
I've kept postponing:  i.e. create (my first) JSFiddle.
(Who knows...I might discover something in my new HTML / JS that is causing this problem.)  That could take me some time...stay tuned.